# Web Consistency Testing & Selenium : is there any tool which we can integrate with selenium to perform Web consistency testing

Tags: selenium, cross-browser, web-testing

Web Consistency Testing & Selenium : is there any tool which we can integrate with selenium to perform Web consistency testing

I can do this using Selenium but its scope is limited using getallButtons, getAllFields etc. but it does not fetch all Page elements and also it only fetches only buttons or labels not every GUI element which are actually causing problems

So is there any Web consistency tool which can(prefered) or can not be integrated with selenium?

Also please suggest any others ways you know to perform this without selenium or with selenium

Comment: You might want to try the [Software Quality Stackexchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[Mogotest](http://mogotest.com/) is the tool designed for this testing. It is commercial though.

http://webconsistencytesting.com/

Comment: Thanks but MOGOTEST is commercial, i need a free one :)

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you can obtain all page elements with Web Driver using xpath search

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
```

But processing those elements is so slow that renders this method virtually useless. Assuming you would like to invoke WebDriver's getTagName(), getLocation() and getSize() methods on every element of the web page it would take average 10 seconds (measured for a page with 190 elements which is relatively small).

If time is important for you, you need to go for difficult method which is serializing DOM to JSON or XML using javascript (you can inject javascript with Web Driver) and then parsing it in whatever language you're using for writing your Selenium tests.